# Navigation with Go route on Flutter with IOS

Tags: flutter

I have a problem in Flutter with navigating between widgets using the Go Route with the drag that iPhone has. When I go from HomeScreen to DetailsScreen, it works correctly by pressing the button, but when I go back, it's like HomeScreen duplicates and ends up creating a bouncing effect.

This is the code that i used, i put too maintainState in true, false, etc... but this not affect, i think...

```
/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const CupertinoPage(
          maintainState: true,
          child: HomeScreen()),
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
              const CupertinoPage(child: DetailsScreen()),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

/// The main app.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
    );
  }
}

/// The home screen
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [HomeScreen]
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              statesController: MaterialStatesController(),
              onPressed: () => context.go('/details'),
              child: const Text('Go to the Details screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The details screen
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [DetailsScreen]
  const DetailsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <ElevatedButton>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
              child: const Text('Go back to the Home screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

THIS IS THE "ERROR OR THAT HAPPEND!":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KttM.gif)

I would like to do the correct navigation and not repeat that.